# In the Drivers Editor f-curve, can I prevent keys from snapping to integer keyframes?

Tags: animation, drivers, snapping, fcurves, motion-capture

I am using the Drivers Editor in my motion capture pipeline. I have already recorded a trial video using facial markers, tracked the markers and converted the constraints on the empties to f-curves. Now I am using the Drivers Editor to control the rig with the empties.

[image: Using Drivers Editor]

After some initial experimenting, I realised that the relationship between empty and bone movement is not linear. So I started editing the f-curves to approximate the movements of the my face onto the character.

My problem is that, for example, the distance between the jaw closed and fully down is just 17 mm. I would like to insert several keys between these two extremes to easily control the f-curve.

[image: Key added at 0.51 with value 0.04]

I can insert a key and set its position to, e.g. 10 mm, but as soon as I try to move it in the editor, it snaps to the nearest integer (meter!!!). I have tried moving the key on the y-axis only by entering "G-Y" but as soon as I hit "G" the key position snaps to the nearest integer.

[image: After hitting "G", the key snaps to nearest integer (1.0)]

I can adjust the value of the key in the text-box without the key position snapping, but this is not very intuitive. I guess I could also scale the parent of the empties X 1,000, but this would mean setting up a separate 3D viewport to observe and select them.

So, before I proceed too far with one of these strategies, can anyone tell me if there is a way to prevent keys from snapping?

Comment: Look at your last screenshot, in the top right side there's a dropdown menu for snapping: now is "Nearest frame". Change it as needed.

Comment: Thanks Josh! I honestly thought I looked everywhere for it. I expected there would be a reference to it in the menus. Anyway, do you want to change your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full credit goes to Josh Sanfelici for this. I'm just making it easier for others to find. From Josh: 'Look at your last screenshot, in the top right side there's a dropdown menu for snapping: now is "Nearest frame". Change it as needed.'

[image]